# Detect rectangular portraits of people on images with OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, image-recognition, vision

I have many images of yearbooks with people portraits and I'm trying to build an algorytm that will detect those portraits. At least, to detect correct rectangular portraits. [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twHVm.jpg) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08KXn.jpg)

I'm trying to investigate three directions:

1. Face detection
2. Dark rectangles detection (Since portraits are usually darker shapes on brighter background)
3. People name extraction from OCR'ed texts

By combining results of three algorithms above, I hope to get some methodology, that will be applicable for many different yearbooks pages.

I would be very appreciate for any help for the rectangles detection.
I started with Java and OpenCV 3.

Here is my code applied for [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twHVm.jpg):

```java
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread("Path/to/image", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());

Imgproc.cvtColor(source, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(destination, destination, new Size(5, 5), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT);

int threshold = 100;
Imgproc.Canny(destination, destination, 50, 100);
Imgproc.Canny(destination, destination, threshold, threshold*3);
```

At this point, I have such result: 
[image]

Trying to find contours from the edges above:

```java
    List<MatOfPoint> contourDetections = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    // Find contours
    Imgproc.findContours(destination, contourDetections, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Draw contours 
    Imgproc.drawContours(source, contours, -1, new Scalar(255,0,0), 2);
```

Getting this result:
[image]

But not sure how to extract rectangles from those contours since many of lines are incomplete.

Getting back to edges and trying to find vertical and horizontal lines using HoughLinesP:

```java
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int thre = 50;
    int minLineSize = 250;
    int lineGap = 80;

    int ignoreLinesShorter = 300;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(destination, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, thre, minLineSize, lineGap);

    for(int c = 0; c < lines.rows(); c++) {

        double[] vec = lines.get(c, 0);

        double  x1 = vec[0],
                y1 = vec[1],
                x2 = vec[2],
                y2 = vec[3];

        // Filtering only verticat and horizontal lines
        if(x1 == x2 || y1 == y2) {

            // Filtering out short lines
            if(Math.abs(x1 - x2) > ignoreLinesShorter || Math.abs(y1 - y2) > ignoreLinesShorter) {

              Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
              Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

              // Draw line
              Imgproc.line(source, start, end, new Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Like with contours, I'm still not seeing correct rectangles that I could detect. Could you help me with a correct direction? Maybe there is an easier way to perform this task?

Comment: The contours are incomplete because the edges are incomplete. Have you tried lower threshold values in Canny? Also you can filter the smaller contours out by size with `contourArea`.

Comment: How about *increase* the contour's threshold and then extend all the vertical and horizontal lines?

Comment: Were you ever able to develop a robust algorithm to detect rectangular portraits in yearbooks? I'm wanting to do this with 85 yearbooks from my alma mater. I provided an answer to your question the outperforms the answer by @sturkmen using the reduce() function, but it is still not as robust as I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting rectangular portraits (headshots), I've had some success with the following methodology.

1. **Rectangle Detection:**
   *a. Convert to grayscale*
   *b. Change color of image border to background color*
   *c. Binary Thresholding*
   *d. Closing Morphological Transformation*
   *e. Invert image if necessary*
   *f. Find contours*
   *g. Choose rectangular contours based on aspect ratio and area*
2. **Face Detection:** *Find the rectangular contours that contain headshots using Haar cascade. To be a headshot portrait, a rectangle should contain only one face with dimensions of face specified relative to size of the rectangle. For example, when using OpenCv CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale, set minSize=(0.4 * width, 0.3 * height) for face size where height and width are the dimensions of rectangle.*
3. **Portrait Validation:** *Check for grid structure of portrait rectangles. For missing rectangles in grid, check if face exists. For existing rectangles, use grid structure to correct rectangle dimensions if necessary.*

---

**1. Python code for rectangle detection** *(It should be easy to convert to Java.)*

```
img = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Remove black border by cropping
bw = 6 # border width
ht, wd = img.shape[:2] # height, width
gray = gray[bw:ht-bw, bw:wd-bw]

# HISTOGRAM -- Put histogram function here to determine the following:
bg_color = (235,235,235) # background color
thresh_value = 220

# Add back border with background color
gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, bw, bw, bw, bw, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=bg_color)

# Binary Threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] # orig: 235

# Closing Morphological Transformation
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Invert Image
closing = np.invert(closing)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Find portraits by specifying range of sizes and aspect ratios
img_area = ht * wd
for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if w*h < 0.005*img_area or w*h > 0.16*img_area or h/w < 0.95 or h/w > 1.55:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

**Example 1 Result** *(First image is after inverting.)*
[image: Example 1]

**Example 2 Result**
[image: Example 2]

---

**2. Python code for face detection**

```
def is_headshot(cnt_img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(cnt_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    height, width = cnt_img.shape[:2]
    min_size = int(max(0.4*width, 0.3*height))
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 
                                          scaleFactor=1.3, 
                                          minNeighbors=3, 
                                          minSize=(min_size, min_size))
    if len(faces) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) # bounding rectangle of contour found in code above
if is_headshot(img[y:y+h, x:x+w]):
    cv2.imwrite('headshot.jpg', img[y:y+h, x:x+w])
```

---

**3. Python code for portrait validation**
The grid structure can be found using code I posted in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946604/fitting-a-uniform-grid-to-coordinates-with-random-errors). Loop through the results of the completed grid. Each grid element is defined by (x,y,w,h) where w and h can be the average width and height of portraits found above. Use the function box1.intersection(box2) from shapely.geometry to determine if there are missing or missized portraits. If the intersection area is small or zero, there may be a missing portrait that should then be checked with face detection. I'm open to providing more details if there is any interest.

Answer (score 4):

it is not a complete answer but maybe useful.

i get the image below with the following code.

to understand the code you can refer to my old answer at http://answers.opencv.org/question/85884

if it seems promising we will try to improve it together.

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img = imread("e:/test/twHVm.jpg");
    if (img.empty())
        return -1;

    Mat resized, gray, reduced_h, reduced_w;
    resize(img, resized, Size(), 1, 1);

    cvtColor(resized, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    reduce(gray, reduced_h, 0, REDUCE_AVG);
    reduce(gray, reduced_w, 1, REDUCE_AVG);


    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
    {
        if (reduced_h.at<uchar>(0, i) > 200) // this is experimental value
        line(resized, Point(i, 0), Point(i, img.rows), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
    {
        if (reduced_w.at<uchar>(i, 0) > 225) // this is experimental value
        line(resized, Point(0, i), Point(img.cols, i), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    }

    imshow("result", resized);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, used to work on a similar project. I had some photos that were rotated and I had to make them look normal (rotate to a normal state). So I managed to detect whether they are horizontal or vertical and rotate them. But could not detect if they are mirrored

Comment: you can ask another question with a sample image and your code.let me see if i help you.

Comment: You have a good result, thanks. I'll tale a look at your code.